# conjure-up kubernetes on MAAS

Tags: juju, maas, conjure-up, kubernetes

MAAS + JUJU + Conjure-up + Kuberntes
after all setting about proxy, I get this error:

Attempting to connect to 192.168.100.101:22 
Bootstrap agent now started
Contacting Juju controller at 192.168.100.101 to verify accessibility
***ERROR unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: Forbidden***

Answer (score 0):

1. Removed lxd and lxd-client
2. Installed snal lxd (sudo install snap lxd)
3. Restarted